# Android canvas update issues

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm simply not getting this to work.
I saw that this network isn't for just simple code correcting posts.
But I think this is in the interest of others to because there werent any good tutorials.

So I'm calling a canvas and I can draw on it in the `ondraw()` method but when I try to draw out of the game loop it draws nothing. I even don't get an error messasge.

App :

```
public class App extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        draw d = new draw(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(d);

    }
    public void end()
    {
        App.this.finish();
    }
}
```

draw.java :

```
public class draw extends View {
    Canvas ca;
    View v;
    Paint paint;

    int width;
    int height;

    static final int MAX_GAME_SPEED=33;
    static int fps; 
    boolean running=true;



    int pw=0,ph=0;





    public draw(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }  

            @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        super.onDraw(c);
        paint = new Paint(); //Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);


        //get screen size
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();


        width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
        height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated







            // make the entire canvas white
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            c.drawPaint(paint);


            ca = c;
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            c.drawRect(Math.round(width/3),Math.round(height/3),Math.round((width/3)*2),Math.round((height/3)*2), paint); //position width, position height,width,height


            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setTextSize(30);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            c.drawText(String.valueOf(width)+"x"+String.valueOf(height)+","+Math.round(width/3)+"x"+Math.round(height/3), 30, 200, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            c.drawText(String.valueOf(width)+"x"+String.valueOf(height)+","+Math.round(width/3)+"x"+Math.round(height/3), 30, 200, paint);


            Thread myThread = new Thread(new UpdateThread());
            myThread.start();

    }
            public void paint(Canvas c)
            {

                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                c.drawRect(20, 5, 50, 100, paint);

                pw++;
                ph++;



                /*if (pw >= width || ph >= height)
                {
                    pw=0;
                    ph=0;
                }
                */

            }
            public Handler updateHandler = new Handler(){
                /** Gets called on every message that is received */
                // @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                   paint(ca);


                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            };



            public class UpdateThread implements Runnable {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     while(true){
                         draw.this.updateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    }
                }

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly:
You are sending update messages too often. I belive you are overloading your message queue with that.

Secondly:
You are using canvas instance saved at onDraw method. I think this is not right.
Instead, you can change your UpdateThread.run() method to

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        draw.this.postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

This will send message to invalidate and repaint your View and thus call to your View.onDraw(Canvas) method with proper Canvas.

Also:
If you want to render your View as much as possible you must to implement next sequence:

```
static final int MSG_REDRAW = 1;

Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_REDRAW:
            // This method invoked on UI thread - ok.
            draw.this.invalidate();
            sendEmptyMessage(MSG_REDRAW);
            break;

        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and instead of scheduling thread (UpdateThread) you need to just send first MSG_REDRAW message.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a View and in the onDraw() you're creating a Thread that does the drawing?  Why?  You should be doing all of the drawing on the UI thread and farming the other parts of your game of to other threads.

Comment: I am building this with and old java tutorial which I have used to make the same gmae for a java phone but how do you mean how can I do that ?

Comment: If you're doing something like a game you should really be using a SurfaceView since it allows better speeds.  Here's a tutorial on how to do that: http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3281/android-the-basics-33-review-of-surfaceview-and-thread-setup/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra thread.

Just invalidate as last statement in onDraw and onDraw will scheduled again.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with postInvalidate and thread.
first of all try to add `setWillNotDraw(false);`
and i had a problem while screen changed orientation- it's took a lot of time for redrawing by postInvalidate() because of calling this function we doesn't know when onDraw will be called really but it will be.
for my solution and question about this look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855912/surfaceview-ondraw-and-postinvalidate-something-wrong).